# How i can use PhoneGap to create ios app in windows os?

Tags: ios, mobile

hi I am beginner in **IOS** mobile I know that i must have Apple device to work on it to create **IOS** app . my project is that i am preparing to work on it is **HTML5** and **Javascript** and **css** when i searched i found that **PhoneGap** can do it without more codes .so how i can work on **phonegap** in **windows os** if i dont have apple device?. I hope you will help me on this issue.

Comment: try this link http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/detailed_guide_for_setting_up_building_ios_apps_without_a_mac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can found the **Developer Platform Guide** for your question

[PhoneGap Developer Guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/guide_getting-started_index.md.html#Platform%20Guides)
Your App in fact is a HTML5 With Javascript and you can convert for all Devices support this architecture, in the link you see all list for different platform.

[image]

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 4):

You will have to use cloud building tools like [Phonegap build](http://build.phonegap.com) or [Intel XDK](http://xdk-software.intel.com/) to develop iOS app without a Mac.

With Phonegap build, you will have to create a `config.xml`, zip this along with the app written in HTML5/CSS/JS and upload it to Phonegap build and it will give back a `.ipa` iOS app file to download, which can be installed on iOS device for testing. But to do the build, you will need to upload a exported developer certificate (.p12 file) from a Mac and upload to phonegap build before you can build the app. You just need the certificate exported from a Mac, you can get this certificate and use Window PC to upload the certificate and start building iOS apps from windows PC

With Intel XDK, you can develop app using HTML5/CSS/JS, simulate app on various devices and build app in cloud just like with phonegap build. But you dont need a Mac for exporting certificates and stuff, Intel XDK generates a Certificate Signing Request(CSR), which you will have to upload to apple developer site to get a certificate. You you do not need a Mac at all to start building iOS apps.

But in both cases you will require a Mac when you want to submit the app to Apple AppStore, you will have to use the XCode -> Application Loader to upload the iOS app binary to submit to AppStore.

Answer (score 1):

Phonegap requires native environment to wrap your html,css,javascript and produce a native build.

iOS native environment requires Mac OSX.

AFIK, you cannot do iOS development in windows OS.

On work around you can consider doing is using Phonegap's [online build service](https://build.phonegap.com)

Answer (score 0):

The only possible way building for iOS without touching a Mac would be Phonegap's cloud building service.
[Phonegap Build FAQ](https://build.phonegap.com/faq)

You would still need both of:

- some device for testing purposes
- an Apple Developer account