# how to wrap code of android app to ios using the phonegap?

Tags: android, ios, eclipse, cordova

I have successfully build the apps in phonegap for android which is developed in eclipse on windows. In that apps I have created the splash screen using following code

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.init();

    super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen",R.drawable.splash);
    // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
    super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl(),5000);
    //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}
```

But now I want to convert this entire code which is made in eclipse in iPhone so I can create ipa.
I have already have code for android (like html,css, js). 
**Q.1**. how can I create splash screen in iphone 
**Q.2.** how can to wrap this code in iphone but I don't have the mac system.
 I just want to create all code for ios on windows through command prompt and create ipa on phonegap build so is this correct way to do that? I am using phonegap 3.4 version.

Answer (score 0):

I have not really worked on phonegap. But I've worked with unity and it provides option to add a splash screen for iOS games. Try referring to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444854/how-i-can-use-phonegap-to-create-ios-app-in-windows-os).
Thought this might help.

Answer (score 0):

Splash screen in iOS applications is to be added using launch images that are specified in the  application's info.plist file. Mostly the image names are

Default.png (iPhone)

Default@2x.png (iPhone Retina 3.5 inch)

Default-568h@2x.png (iPhone Retina 4 inch)

Default-Portrait.png (iPad in portrait orientation)

Default-Portrait@2x.png (iPad Retina in portrait orientation)

Default-Landscape.png (iPad in landscape orientation)

Default-Landscape@2x.png (iPad Retina in landscape orientation)

Create such images, add it to the iPhone project that is generated and link them in the info.plist file to get your splash screens.